# iFrame in PWA (Progressive Web App) - 2 calls for Offline

Tags: iframe, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I am currently working on Progressive Web App.
I'm trying to create a PWA with an iFrame.

The problem is that I have to load the page twice, else that it can't be available offline.
Files are properlu cached on the first call but I realized that the fetch was only called for the second load. Is there a connection ?
If not, do you have any other idea where the problem might come from?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if my own issue is connected, but here's what I'm trying to solve: I have a microfrontend site that leverages iframes for partials/components. There is a header, a footer, a menu, and a router component -- 4 total. These all load and get cached just fine by the PWA Service Worker. However, because the router is triggered asynchronously by a HashChangeEvent, the component that should appear for the given route does not get cached (for some reason). It is possible that my issue is because the iframe for the route gets appended to the DOM and is not part of the router's actual HTML.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because of the waiting phase, check the [lifecycle of service workers and how to skip the waiting phase](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle#skip_the_waiting_phase).

Comment: I understood the use of the waiting phase. However, that doesn't solicit my problem.
My service worker is activated from the start, datas is in cache but they are not called after the first offline (if there was only one call)

Comment: Hmmm, did you check if it works without iFrame, do you use any tools like sw-precache, sw-toolbox or workbox?

Comment: It works without iFrame. I don't use these tools.
And, I tried workbox but it doesn't work better.